# Java thread pooled complex constraints data processing

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have Java EE (desktop) application that had to process data files generated by multiple sources (up to a 200 different sources). Each source periodically generates **data file with unique name** which also contains that source's unique ID.

I need to create a thread pool with 15 threads which will process and remove files with these constraints:

1. Multiple threads can't process files from the same source simultaneously.
2. Multiple files from the same source should be processed in order of it's creation timestamp.
3. No synchronization with the file generator sources is possible so it means that the next file(s) may be generated by source while it's previous file is processed or scheduled for processing.
4. Processing should be multi threaded because of performance reasons (single threaded processing is not enough so I'm planning to use 10-15 threads).
5. A file processing operation may be time consuming 3-15 seconds.

Any suggestions on architecture of such complex synchronization of the threads in pool are welcome.

P.S. Due to the limitation on simultaneous processing the design I've used in more simple situations earlier i.e. using ArrayBlockingQueue does not fit this case.

Comment: You might want to check what Spring Batch Integration may offer you https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html

Comment: Why not PriorityBlockingQueue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General idea:

You have a task-queue per source.

And you have a central queue which is effectively a queue of task-queues which is shared between all worker threads.

For each source you create a task-queue. And you stick these task-queue's in a hashtable based on the unique id. This way you get the guarantee that tasks from the same source are processed in order (requirement 2).

If a tasks is received, you look up (or create) the task-queue in the hashtable and you add the task to the taskqueue. If it was the first task added to the queue, you also add it to the central queue.

Then there are a bunch of worker-threads that take task-queues from this central queue and then take a single task from this task-queue they just took and process that task. Once they are done with the task, they need to decide if the task-queue needs to be reinserted back into the central-queue or not.

There are a few parts were things could easily go wrong:

1. You don't want to end up with a task-queue being inserted into the central-queue multiple times. That would violate your first requirement.
2. You don't want the task-queue not being reinserted into the central-queue even though a task is available.

So you need to take care of the appropriate synchronization and it might be a bit more complex than you would initially think. But seen the fact that the tasks are long running, I would start out with a regular mutex (could be per task-queue) e.g. synchronized or a lock and don't worry about making it non blocking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had come to a similar thought when read Spring Batch docs suggested by Alexander Pavlov's comment. Right now I'm thinking about using my older lib https://github.com/Zur13/Checkpoint instead of mutext with architecture you have described

Comment: I'll check it out in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the skeleton/tester of the class I've created to solve my problem. See @pveentjer answer for some details on whats going on here.

```
package org.zur.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class PmFileProcessor {
    private static final int THREADS_COUNT = 15;

    ArrayBlockingQueue<File> scheduledFiles = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10000, false);
    HashMap<String, PmFileProcessingJob> allJobs = new HashMap<>();

    ScheduledExecutorService jobsExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(THREADS_COUNT);

    public PmFileProcessor() {
        super();

        SourceJobsManager fc = new SourceJobsManager();
        fc.setDaemon(true);
        fc.start();
    }

    public void scheduleFile(File f) {
        try {
            scheduledFiles.add(f);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    /**
     * Assigns files to file source processing job.
     *
     * @author
     *         <ul>
     *         <li>Zur13</li>
     *         </ul>
     *
     */
    public class SourceJobsManager extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // assigns scheduled files to per-source jobs and schedules job for additional execution
            while ( true ) {
                try {
                    File f = scheduledFiles.take();
                    PmFileProcessingJob job = getSourceJob(f);
                    job.scheduleSourceFile(f);
                    jobsExecutorService.execute(job); // schedules job execution

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // TODO: check disk space periodically
            }

        }

        /**
         * Finds existing job for file source or creates a new one.
         * 
         * @param f
         * @return
         */
        private PmFileProcessingJob getSourceJob(File f) {
            // TODO: test code
            String fname = f.getName();
            String[] parts = fname.split("_");
            String uid = parts[0];
            PmFileProcessingJob res = allJobs.get(uid);
            if ( res == null ) {
                res = new PmFileProcessingJob(uid);
                allJobs.put(uid, res);
            }
            return res;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Process first file from scheduledSourceFiles queue (i.e. each job execution processes a single file or
     * reschedules itself for later execution if another thread already processes the file from the same source).
     *
     * @author
     *         <ul>
     *         <li>Zur13</li>
     *         </ul>
     *
     */
    public class PmFileProcessingJob implements Runnable {
        public final String fileSourceUidString;

        PriorityQueue<File> scheduledSourceFiles = new PriorityQueue<>(1000, new Comparator<File>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }
        });

        Semaphore onePassSemaphore = new Semaphore(1);

        public PmFileProcessingJob(String fileSourceUid) {
            super();
            this.fileSourceUidString = fileSourceUid;
        }

        /**
         * Schedules file from for processing by this job.
         */
        public void scheduleSourceFile(File f) {
            scheduledSourceFiles.add(f);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            File f = null;
            if ( scheduledSourceFiles.size() > 0 ) { // fail fast optimization 1
                if ( onePassSemaphore.tryAcquire() ) { // fail fast optimization 2
                    try {
                        f = scheduledSourceFiles.poll();
                        if ( f != null ) {
                            // TODO: process the file
                            try {
                                System.err.println(f.getName() + "\t" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                                return;
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                                return; // prevents reschedule loop for failing files
                            }
                        } else {
                            // scheduledSourceFiles queue is empty
                            return;
                        }
                    } finally {
                        onePassSemaphore.release();
                    }
                }
                if ( f == null && scheduledSourceFiles.size() > 0 ) {
                    // this thread did not process the scheduled file because another thread holds the critical section
                    // pass
                    // this thread should reschedule this Job to release this thread and try to process this job later
                    // with another thread
                    // reschedule the job with 4 seconds delay to prevent excess CPU usage
                    // System.err.println("RESCHEDULE");
                    jobsExecutorService.schedule(this, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((this.fileSourceUidString == null) ? 0 : this.fileSourceUidString.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if ( this == obj )
                return true;
            if ( !(obj instanceof PmFileProcessingJob) )
                return false;
            PmFileProcessingJob other = (PmFileProcessingJob) obj;
            if ( this.fileSourceUidString == null ) {
                if ( other.fileSourceUidString != null )
                    return false;
            } else if ( !this.fileSourceUidString.equals(other.fileSourceUidString) )
                return false;
            return true;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PmFileProcessor fp = new PmFileProcessor();
        fp.unitTest();
    }

    private void unitTest() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int filesCount = 1000;
        for (int i = 0; i < filesCount; i++) {
            int sourceUid = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 30);
            File f = new File(sourceUid + "_" + i);
            scheduleFile(f);
        }
        Thread.yield();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(999000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```